# How to prioritize Nested JavaScript events?

Tags: javascript, html, events

I have an edit button inside a table cell.

The table cell event has an "click" event, And the edit button who is inside a cell has another click event set to it.

Is there a way to prioritize the button event over the table cell event?

I tried using a different z-index for the button, but it didn't work.

The button cannot go outside the the table as its closest tr holds id data which is crucial for the proper event to function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call event.stopPropagation() as part of the click handler for the button, to prevent the click event from bubbling up to the table cell. Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Answer (score 0):

Inside the click handler on the button, you just need to call `event.stopPropagation()`.

```
element.onclick= function(event) {
    // ...
    event.stopPropagation();
    // ...
}
```

Look into a tutorial on bubbling and capturing events, such as http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing